# Select rows from the past 24 hours until a certain hour this morning

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I want to select all the rows in my database from the last 24 hours but not until the current time every time, but up until a certain hour of today. what should i add the following statement?

So far i get the results from the last 24 hours whenever a user visits the web page using the following statement:

```
tad510.t_edte >= DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) -- t_edte is a datetime
```

But the problem is i want to show the results of the past 24 hours just up until 5AM of the day in which the function is being called from the controller of the view.

I was thinking like doing something in the lines of:

```
tad510.t_edte > DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE())+'05:00:00'
```

but i'm not sure if it's even correct

It would be really helpful if you guys can tell me how i can do it so i get the results expected. 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? That are completely different products. That snippet *looks* like T-SQL, which suggests SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL server. Please dont mix tags of different RDBMS

Comment: Ah sorry it's for SQL-Server

Comment: What if it is 2019-10-02 4AM? Do you want to display all data between 2019-10-01 5AM to 2019-10-02 5AM?

Comment: @SalmanA yes exactly that

Comment: Please provide a sample data and expected results as _formatted text_ **not images**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a WHERE clause such as this:

```
WHERE t_edte >= DATEADD(HOUR, -19, CAST(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
  AND t_edte <  DATEADD(HOUR,   5, CAST(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

On `2019-10-02 07:16:54.453` it'll fetch data between `2019-10-01 05:00` and `2019-10-02 05:00`. [Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d48c73babd308748cc3e02e8fe7a715e).

Comment: Can you pls explain your answer to me further? thnx

Comment: @achraf the two `DATEADD` functions will calculate 5:00AM yesterday and 5:00AM today. [See this fiddle for example cases](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d48c73babd308748cc3e02e8fe7a715e)

Comment: so if i call this function, let's say for example on 04th October at 10:15am, it would still show the results between 3rd October at 05:00am until 4th October at 05:00AM? and not from 10:15 to 05:00 unlike the answer above?
Thanks1

Comment: It should show dates between 3rd October 05:00am to 4th October 05:00AM. I have not tested but you can check the fiddle... edit the dates to test and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

One method, cast `GETDATE()` to a `date` (then back to a `datetime`) and add 5 hours to it.

```
WHERE tttaad510100.t_edte >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
  AND tttaad510100.t_edte < DATEADD(HOUR, 5, CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: Probably remove the `Select` from the `Where` clause. :-)

Comment: Opps, that was from testing. thansk @WEI_DBA

Comment: @Larnu so if i call this function, let's say for example on 04th October at 10:15am, it would still show the results between 3rd October at 05:00am until 4th October at 05:00AM?

Comment: No, 10:15 to 05:00 @AchrafRAGUI . 05:00 the prior say was more than 24 hours ago.